# What wordpress template to use for a "/?post_types=boardgames" URL?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a url
**http://www.sitename.com/?post_types=boardgames**
that shows all posts of this post-type but it doesn't use my custom template for **archive.php** or **search.php**.

I tried **archive-boardgames.php** and **search-boardgames.php** but that doesn't work.

**The url [www.sitename.com/boardgames/](http://www.sitename.com/boardgames/) does show the correct template, so I don't think it's a template error issue.**

The url is generated by the plugin "**Search & Filter**" when using the All option on the select menu.
*Archive is set to true for the custom post-type.*

I tried this in the htaccess, but it doesn't redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /?post_types=boardgames http://www.sitename.com/boardgames/
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To display your Search results, and search within a specific post type Archive set the Display Method to Post Type Archive (found in the Display Results tab)

Resource : https://searchandfilter.com/documentation/search-results/as-a-post-type-archive/

Comment: Thanks but I have the free version, so nothing can be edited.  There are no settings or tabs. It must be locked away in the pro version.